# How to pass a certain path to url param in ajax with asp.net mvc

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I would like to know if it is possible to built the ajax url param?

For example in the next function I will sent two params **controllerToCall** and **methodToCall**, is it possible to build with them somethink like:

```
'@Url.Action("method", "controller")'


function ListaPubliP(id1, id2, sec, controllerToCall, methodToCall) {
    var data = {
        Id: id1,
        Sec: id2,
        Ser: sec
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: '@Url.Action(methodToCall, controllerToCall)',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        dataType: "json",
```

Comment: your requirement is not cleared. But the way using @Url.Action in Ajax that is not possible. I may help if requirement is clear.

Comment: @ManojKS : my question is: how to build ajax's url parameter with code. example: `str= "@Url.Action(" + param1 + "," + param2 + ")"`. And that str pass to url: str;

Comment: I think, it is not possible. you can do like this in Ajax with Url: http://localhost:123/Home/Test/param1/param2.